# How to optimize $\max_{ \|a \| \le r } E[ \|a+Z\|^k]$ where $Z$ i.i.d. Gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimization, expectation

Let $\| \cdot \|$ be a Euclidean distance.
How to optimize 
\begin{align}
\max_{ \|a  \| \le r } E[ \|a+Z\|^k],
\end{align}
where $Z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is i.i.d. Gaussian standard normal and $k>0$?

**Solution for the case of $n=1$.**

For $n=1$ I found that 
\begin{align}
E[|a+Z|^k]= \frac{2^{k/2} \Gamma \left(\frac{k+1}{2} \right)}{\sqrt{\pi}}F_{1,1} \left(-\frac{k}{2},\frac{1}{2}; -\frac{a^2}{2} \right),
\end{align}
where $F_{1,1}$ is the Kummer’s confluent hypergeometric function. 
Since, $f(x)=F_{1,1} \left(-\frac{k}{2},\frac{1}{2}; -\frac{x^2}{2} \right)$ is increasing $x$ it follows that

\begin{align}
\max_{|a| \le r }E[|a+Z|^k]=  E[|r+Z|^k].
\end{align}

**My Question:** How can we find the maximum for any dimension $n\ge 1$?

My conjecture is that the optimal value of $a$ is such that  $\|a \|=r$. That is $a$ is  a point on a ball of radius $r$.

Thanks.

Comment: Clearly the $a$ in your conjecture is a KKT point. Do you see this?

Comment: @RobertHannah89  No. I would really like some explanation.

Comment: Convex functions are maximized at extreme points.  Can you show $f(a) = E[||a+Z||^k]$ is convex in $a$?

Comment: Alternatively, you can reduce to the 1-d case by arguing that $f(a)$ depends only on the magnitude of $a$, not its orientation.

Comment: @Michael I can see how  $f(a)$ only depends on the magnitude of $a$ but not sure how to proceed next.  Also not very sure how to show that $f(a)$ is convex due to the norm.  Be great if you can put in some details.

Comment: It would be convex for $k\geq 1$, you can think of it as a composition of the convex norm function and the convex $x^k$ function defined for $x\geq 0$. For $k<1$ it may not be convex.

Comment: What is the context of this question?  Is it a homework problem?

Comment: I was working on the $n=1$ case and had a question of how this can be extended to higher dimensions.  I know understand the case of $k \ge 1$. Do you have any idea of how to show it for $k<1$?

Comment: See my edits below.

Comment: @RobertHannah89 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple Lagrange multiplier problem. Let's look at the gradient (where it is defined: i.e. not at the origin)

\begin{align}
\nabla_a f(a) = \mathbb{E}[k\|a+X\|^{k-2}a]
\end{align}

This (sub)gradient is never $0$ except at the origin. The solution must either be at the origin (which you can obviously eliminate) or on the boundary at a KKT point. The constraint can we phrased as $g(a) = \|a\|^2-r^2 \leq 0$. KKT conditions:

\begin{align}
\nabla_a f(a) &= \lambda \nabla g(a)\\
\mathbb{E}[k\|a+X\|^{k-2}]a &= 2\lambda a
\end{align}

Clearly this is satisfied for any $\|a\|=r$, using

\begin{align}
\lambda = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[k\|a+X\|^{k-2}]
\end{align}

Hence any point on the boundary is a solution to the maximization problem by radial symmetry, and the fact that the origin is not a solution.

**Edit**: In response to comments. You don't really need to prove convexity to do this problem. $f$ is not differentiable, but we can use a version of KKT for nondifferentiable functions.

It can be shown that for $k\geq1$ that this function is convex. From Proposition 8.18 of *Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces, Bauschke and Combettes*, it can be shown that so long as the 1D version of a radially symmetric function (i.e. only depends on the norm) is convex, the ND version of this function is also convex. The 1D version of $f$ is convex for $k\geq 1$, hence $f$ is convex for $k\geq 1$.

For $0< k < 1$, the function is what's called *quasiconvex*. See *Bauschke and Combettes, Example 10.28* for this result. This is similar, in that it will be maximized at extreme points (points on the boundary).  See *Maximizing and minimizing quasiconvex functions: related properties, existence and optimality conditions via radial epiderivatives, Fabian Flores-Bazan Fernando Flores-Bazan Cristian Vera*.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me how you got the the gradient? Why is it $k-2$ not $k-1$?

Comment: Just simple partial integration on $a$ with the chain rule. It's $k-2$ and $1$: Notice there is an $a$ on the end of the expression.

Comment: Does the result change if  we introduce an extra matrix $K$ and try to optimize $\max_{ \|a\| \le r}  E{ \| Ka+Z\|}$?? Is the maximum still the same?

Comment: Well yeah. So your original $f$ is radial, and is strictly increasing radially. Therefore the maximum will occur at points of largest norm. So finding the maximizers is equivalent to finding $\arg\max_{\|a\|\leq r} \|Ka\|$ (i.e. just totally ignore the Gaussian and the value of $k>0$). The solution set can also be written as $a$ such that $\|a\|=r$ and $\|Ka\|=\|K\|\times\|a\|$.

Comment: How did you get $\| Ka \|=\| K\| \|a\|$, since $K$ is matrix, can you do it?

Comment: $\|K\|$ refers to the [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm).

Comment: But $a$ is a vector. Which matrix norm satisfies this property?

Comment: Just ignore the last sentence, you can understand without it. This is just the $L^2$ matrix norm which is defined as: $\|K\|=\sup_{\|v\|=1}\|Kv\|$.